# Help required on want to add Twitter OAuth just like facebook connect

Tags: twitter, oauth, connect

I want to add twitter oauth just like facebook connect in my site like this site http://mytweeple.com/default.aspx. Need help on this how i can do this.
Regards,

Comment: what did you try so far? Any code examples? What problems dit you encounter?

Comment: i have tried a sample code from this site http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681 and it worked and redirected me to my site but now what i want is how can i check on my site pages that user is logged in or not as we do in facebook connect? 
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ

You can find some [code examples](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples) here.

And a great [walk through guide](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/twitter-development-using-oauth-authenticate-against-twitter-api-walkthroughs).

Comment: I have one question more how can i check on my site pages that user is logged in or not ?

Comment: It is not possible to "sniff" that the user is already logged into twitter - as this would require crossing a domain security boundary.

Comment: no you didnt understand what i want is that i want to check on my site after signing in from twitter connect that user is logged in or not like after signing in callback url was page1.aspx i moved to page2.aspx how i can check on page2.aspx that user is logged in or not ?

Comment: If they login with twitter they'll be redirected to a URL of your choosing (ie; yoursite.com/oauthlogin.aspx) If they choose not to then they'll never get to that page. So in your oauthlogin page, authenticate and remember in session etc.